# Java FizzBuzz 1 Line

Tags: java, fizzbuzz

How can one complete the [FizzBuzz](https://codingbat.com/prob/p153059) exercise *in Codingbat* with just a return statement?

The code that I last used to solve the problem was:

```java
public String[] fizzBuzz(int start, int end) {
  String[] a = new String[end - start];
  for(int i = start; i < end; i++) a[i - start] = i % 15 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz" : i % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz" : i % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" : String.valueOf(i);
  return a;
}
```

My goal is to have code that looks something like this:

```java
public String[] fizzBuzz(int start, int end) {
  return foo;
}
```

---

### Problem

> This is slightly more difficult version of the famous FizzBuzz problem which is sometimes given as a first problem for job interviews. (See also: [FizzBuzz Code](https://codingbat.com/doc/practice/fizzbuzz-code.html).) Consider the series of numbers beginning at **start** and running up to but not including **end**, so for example start=1 and end=5 gives the series 1, 2, 3, 4. Return a new `String[]` array containing the string form of these numbers, except for multiples of 3, use "Fizz" instead of the number, for multiples of 5 use "Buzz", and for multiples of both 3 and 5 use "FizzBuzz". In Java, `String.valueOf(xxx)` will make the String form of an int or other type. This version is a little more complicated than the usual version since you have to allocate and index into an array instead of just printing, and we vary the start/end instead of just always doing 1..100.

---

### Test Cases

```
fizzBuzz(1, 6) → ["1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz"]
fizzBuzz(1, 8) → ["1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7"]
fizzBuzz(1, 11) → ["1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7", "8", "Fizz", "Buzz"]
fizzBuzz(1, 16) → ["1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7", "8", "Fizz", "Buzz", "11", "Fizz", "13", "14", "FizzBuzz"]
fizzBuzz(1, 4) → ["1", "2", "Fizz"]
fizzBuzz(1, 2) → ["1"]
fizzBuzz(50, 56) → ["Buzz", "Fizz", "52", "53", "Fizz", "Buzz"]
fizzBuzz(15, 17) → ["FizzBuzz", "16"]
fizzBuzz(30, 36) → ["FizzBuzz", "31", "32", "Fizz", "34", "Buzz"]
fizzBuzz(1000, 1006) → ["Buzz", "1001", "Fizz", "1003", "1004", "FizzBuzz"]
fizzBuzz(99, 102) → ["Fizz", "Buzz", "101"]
fizzBuzz(14, 20) → ["14", "FizzBuzz", "16", "17", "Fizz", "19"]
```

Comment: This question is better suited to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jrook I'll post it there as well then.

Comment: There is already an answer on that website: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58615/1-2-fizz-4-buzz

Comment: @jrook Mine is not looking for the smallest way to do it. I simply want a way that is compatible with Codingbat and only uses the `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I could imagine without any Java 8 features involves some ugly conversions of arrays to strings, and strings of arrays of strings to arrays of strings with some very ... pragmatic regular expressions. But I guess the solution is not supposed to be pretty anyhow. It passes all the test cases, though, so it achieves all the goals that can be achieved with test-driven development...

## Never write anything even remotely resembling this in real life!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class OneLineFizzBuzz
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OneLineFizzBuzz f = new OneLineFizzBuzz();
        String[] result = f.fizzBuzz(1000, 1006);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

        check(f.fizzBuzz(1, 6), new String[]{"1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz"});
        check(f.fizzBuzz(1, 8), new String[]{"1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7"});
        check(f.fizzBuzz(1, 11), new String[]{"1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7", "8", "Fizz", "Buzz"});
        check(f.fizzBuzz(1, 16), new String[]{"1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7", "8", "Fizz", "Buzz", "11", "Fizz", "13", "14", "FizzBuzz"});
        check(f.fizzBuzz(1, 4), new String[]{"1", "2", "Fizz"});
        check(f.fizzBuzz(1, 2), new String[]{"1"});
        check(f.fizzBuzz(50, 56), new String[]{"Buzz", "Fizz", "52", "53", "Fizz", "Buzz"});
        check(f.fizzBuzz(15, 17), new String[]{"FizzBuzz", "16"});
        check(f.fizzBuzz(30, 36), new String[]{"FizzBuzz", "31", "32", "Fizz", "34", "Buzz"});
        check(f.fizzBuzz(1000, 1006), new String[]{"Buzz", "1001", "Fizz", "1003", "1004", "FizzBuzz"});
        check(f.fizzBuzz(99, 102), new String[]{"Fizz", "Buzz", "101"});
        check(f.fizzBuzz(14, 20), new String[]{"14", "FizzBuzz", "16", "17", "Fizz", "19"});        
    }
    private static void check(String[] fizzBuzz, String[] strings)
    {
        boolean passed = Arrays.equals(fizzBuzz, strings);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fizzBuzz) + " passed? " + passed);
        if (!passed)
        {
            System.out.println("Whoopsie...");
        }
    }

    public String[] fizzBuzz(int start, int end)
    {
        return (start == end ? ""
            : (start % 15 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz"
                : start % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz"
                    : start % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" : String.valueOf(start))
                + Arrays.toString(fizzBuzz(start + 1, end)))
                    .replaceAll("\\]", "").split("\\[|,\\s*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unforunately, in Codingbat, this gives an error:`Bad code`

`Common problems: code should not use println or class or static or exceptions`

Comment: @pythx Not sure what you did, but I just copied the code from my answer into the input field in CodingBat, pressed "Go", and it shows a table with the test cases, all passing.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure exactly why you'd want to do this in a single return statement but nevertheless here it goes:

```
return IntStream.range(start, end)
                .mapToObj(i -> i % 15 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz" : 
                          i % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz" : i % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" : String.valueOf(i))
                .toArray(String[]::new);
```

1. `IntStream.range` returns a sequential ordered `IntStream` from `start` (inclusive) to `end` (exclusive) by an incremental step of 1 which fits exactly in the manner of your imperative approach.
2. `mapToObj` enables us to convert the `IntStream` to a `Stream<String>`.
3. `toArray` enables us to convert the `Stream<String>` to a `String[]` for return.

you can read more about the `IntStream` API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-).

Comment: I used something pretty close to that in pursuit of an answer. The only problem is that in Codingbat, this gives an error: `cannot find symbol IntStream`.

Comment: @pythx it seems codingbat is not allowing you to use the features as of jdk8.  There's no other way to get your code into a single _return statement_ before JDK8. _atleast to my knowledge_.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you have JDK 8(Otherwise this code will not work)
2. Using IntStream.range you can generate integers. and once you have a panch of numbers you have to map them accordingly. (in this case, we have to map them into String [] and check for multiple 3, multiple 5 and multiple 3 & 5 too)
   Now, for the rest of the numbers Using String.valueof() we can add them to the Array.

N.B: make sure to put FIZZBUZZ on the top since it's an if statement only one of them gets executed.

```
    public static String[] foo(int start, int end) {
        return IntStream.range(start, end).mapToObj(i-> ( 
        i%5==0 && i%3==0 ) ? "FIZZBUZZ": 
        i%3==0 ? "FIZZ":
        i%5==0 ? "BUZZ": 
        String.valueOf(i)).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: This should normally work, but unfortunately, Codingbat doesn't support IntStream.

Comment: @pythx yes, It doesn't and if you have seen the question in codingbat they are not asking for a single line code. That was the challenge you bring up. cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

This is short and clear solution which passes all the tests on ***CodingBat***:

```
public String[] fizzBuzz(int start, int end) {
  String[] fizzBuzz = new String[end - start];
  
  for (int i = start, j = 0; i < end; i++, j++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0) {
      fizzBuzz[j] = "FizzBuzz";
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
      fizzBuzz[j] = "Buzz";
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
      fizzBuzz[j] = "Fizz";
    } else {
      fizzBuzz[j] = String.valueOf(i);
    }
  }
  
  return fizzBuzz;
}
```